# This code I wrote fails if I add too many urls to the csv to process. How to improve?

Tags: python

I can run this code, but if I add too many urls to the file aliveSlice, it will error out. I can process somewhere around 3000 at a time, but have a list of 30k

I have no idea, this is the first program I have written in Python.

url examples:

```
https://slicelife.com/restaurants/fl/orlando/32819/triple-pizza-pasta/menu
https://slicelife.com/restaurants/fl/orlando/32819/uno-pizzeria-grill-8250-international-dr-orlando/menu
https://slicelife.com/restaurants/fl/orlando/32820/papa-gio-s-pizza/menu
https://slicelife.com/restaurants/fl/orlando/32821/famas-pizza-pasta/menu
https://slicelife.com/restaurants/fl/orlando/32822/broadway-ristorante-pizzeria/menu
https://slicelife.com/restaurants/fl/orlando/32822/digino-s-new-york-pizzeria/menu
https://slicelife.com/restaurants/fl/orlando/32822/giovannis/menu
https://slicelife.com/restaurants/fl/orlando/32822/i-love-ny-pizza-orlando/menu
https://slicelife.com/restaurants/fl/orlando/32822/mario-s-pizza-subs/menu
https://slicelife.com/restaurants/fl/orlando/32822/muzzarella-pizza-italian-kitchen/menu
https://slicelife.com/restaurants/fl/orlando/32822/napolli-italian-pizzeria/menu
https://slicelife.com/restaurants/fl/orlando/32824/mama-romano-s-orlando/menu
https://slicelife.com/restaurants/fl/orlando/32825/ferrara-pizza-pasta/menu
https://slicelife.com/restaurants/fl/orlando/32825/giovanni-italian-restaurant-pizzeria/menu
https://slicelife.com/restaurants/fl/orlando/32825/italian-village-pizza-orlando/menu
```

program

```
# Open a terminal and input following commands, ensuring that you are in directory that this file is located in within the command environment.
# build the virtual environment:

# python3 -m venv tutorial-env

# activate it

# tutorial-env\Scripts\activate.bat



from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import csv
import sys

pizzaArray = []

with open('aliveSlice.csv') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)

    for url in urls:
        req = requests.get(url[-1])
        content = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

        for pizzeria in content.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "f19xeu2d"}):
            name = pizzeria.find('h1', attrs={"class": "f13p7rsj"})
            address = pizzeria.find('address', attrs={"class": "f1lfckhr"})
            phone = pizzeria.find('button', attrs={"class": "f12gt8lx"})

            if name and address and phone:
                pizzeriaObject = {
                    "pizzeriaName": name.text,
                    "address": address.text,
                    "phoneNumber": phone.text,
                }

                pizzaArray.append(pizzeriaObject)
            else:
                print(f"Missing data - {url}")


with open('pizzeriaData.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    json.dump(pizzaArray, outfile)
```

output

```
[{"pizzeriaName": "Pizzitalia's NY Pizzeria & Italian Restaurant", "address": "6742 Memorial Hwy, Tampa, 33 33515", "phoneNumber": "813-694-1455"}, {"pizzeriaName": "Cecy's Pizza", "address": "1172 Gambell St, Anchorage, AK 99501", "phoneNumber": "907-770-7877"}, {"pizzeriaName": "Fat Ptarmigan", "address": "441 W 5th Ave, Anchorage, AK 99501", "phoneNumber": "907-312-2426"}, {"pizzeriaName": "Glacier Brewhouse", "address": "737 W 5th Ave #110, Anchorage, AK 99501", "phoneNumber": "901-614-1437"}, {"pizzeriaName": "Ski & Benny Pizza", "address": "820 Bilbo St, Anchorage, AK 99501", "phoneNumber": "907-312-1161"}, {"pizzeriaName": "Marco T's Pizzeria", "address": "302 W Fireweed Ln, Anchorage, AK 99503", "phoneNumber": "901-567-8567"}, {"pizzeriaName": "Moose's Tooth Pub & Pizzeria", "address": "3300 Old Seward Hw, Anchorage, AK 99503", "phoneNumber": "901-808-8094"}, {"pizzeriaName": "Palermo Pizza & Philly's", "address": "6406 Debarr Rd, Anchorage, AK 99504", "phoneNumber": "907-334-3354"}, {"pizzeriaName": "Sicily's Pizza", "address": "171 Muldoon Rd #106, Anchorage, AK 99504", "phoneNumber": "906-224-2029"}, {"pizzeriaName": "Sicily's Pizza - Northern Lights ", "address": "2210 E Northern Lights Blvd, Anchorage, AK 99508", "phoneNumber": "901-350-5126"}, {"pizzeriaName": "49th State Brewing Co - Anchorage", "address": "717 W 3rd Ave, Anchorage, AK 99514", "phoneNumber": "901-641-1874"}, {"pizzeriaName": "Sicily's Pizza - East Diamond", "address": "1201 E Dimond Blvd, Anchorage",
```

n/a, force close

Comment: What does it do when "it errors out"?  Do you have a stack trace or error message or something?

Comment: Maybe the site has a rate limit, but in that case I'd expect it to stop you sooner than 3K.

Comment: I can't believe the site really appreciates someone else downloading all their menus. Do you have permission to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sizes you stated in your questions are relatively small, so I don't know if they really are the problem, but the code below might be worth trying if the problem vanishes this way. You can try both modifications independently.

The first point is to read the url file line by line. You also don't need to process it as a csv file, if it just contains the urls.

```
with open('aliveSlice.csv', 'rt') as f:
    url=f.readline()
    req = requests.get(url)
    # here you would do your BeautifulSoup processing
```

The second point could be, that json.dump gets problems with a large collection. You could try to make it's life a bit easier by chopping the collection into pieces and process it document by document:

```
with open('pizzeriaData.json', 'wt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('[')
    sep= ''
    for doc in json_docs:
        f.write(sep)
        f.write(json.dumps(doc))
        sep=', '
    f.write(']')
```